# Inline Span Not Operation

Tags: css

I'm trying to have a correct inline element which will display static text then a 'typewriter' effect back and forth, however it appears it's bumping down annoyingly.

Everything is working minus the span. Can somebody let me know where i'm messing up? Highly assume it's a very basic one!

I hope the below code explains it well enough.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';

import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const TitleContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: left;

    background-color: yellow;
`;

const Tester = () => {
    return (
        <TitleContainer>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                Oppurtunities with... 
            <span>
            <Typewriter
                textStyle={{
                    fontFamily: 'Fire Sans',
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    fontSize: '0.8em',
                    }}
                startDelay={2000}
                cursorColor="#3F3D56"
                options={{
                    strings: [       
                    'Commonwealth Bank',
                    'Deloitte'],
                    autoStart: true,
                    loop: true,
                }}
                />
            </span>
            </Typography>
        </TitleContainer>
    )
}

export default Tester
```

[image]